# Как подключиться к авито используя requests с полученными cookies и headers из selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, requests

Я получаю куки и заголовки из selenium (selenium работает с авито нормально), после чего пытаюсь подключиться к авито через requests, но сервер блокирует меня по причине: 'проблема с ip'. В общем вопрос - как подключиться к авито с полученными cookies и headers используя requests.
Для подключения через selenium юзаю ChromeDriverManager

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import requests
import os


path_to_dir = r'user-data-dir={}\User'.format(os.getcwd())
path_to_driver = os.path.abspath('chromedriver.exe')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')  #
options.add_argument('--enable-profile-shortcut-manager')
options.add_argument(path_to_dir)
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path_to_driver, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
    "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})

driver.get("https://www.avito.ru/")

#получаем куки

all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {}
for cookie in all_cookies:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']

driver.close()
driver.quit()

#конектимся к авито через requests
headers = {
    'authority': 'sntr.avito.ru',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'https://www.avito.ru',
    'referer': 'https://www.avito.ru/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.avito.ru/', cookies=cookies_dict, headers=headers)
```